# jquery-1.11.2.min.js is not working in sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidingmenu

My code of sliding menu is not working in the project although i tested it on jsfiddle it is working there fine but it is not working in my project .actually the problem is in inclusion of file " jquery-1.11.2.min.js" i have also downloaded this file and included in my project and provided a path for the same but still it is not working  this is the code for including the file am i doing anything wrong for including that file

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

this is the path in the directory of my project

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does it load jQuery successfully? What is the error you receive?

Comment: What does your file structure look like? My best guess is that your path is incorrect.

Comment: So are there error messages in the console?

Comment: yes it shows error GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND like this ..and .if i use src path like this  i mean if i include http before //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js  it does not show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a Library like jQuery, it's highly recommended for performances purposes to use a link from the Google Hosted Libraries.

For Jquery 1.11.2, it's :

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js`

Why ? Because a lot of website import libraries from this link, so it's in the user local cache, and it will be load from local almost each time.

Answer (score 0):

> yes it shows error `GET file://`

When run locally `src="//` would default to the local `file://` protocol which will not work.

Use `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"`

Comment: yes i tried  that before.  now it is not showing an error but still it is not working